# jQuery blur based checking and print result to a view in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Possibly someone asked question like as my question. But, I can't find any solution.

**ProfileEditor.php (controller)**

*method 1*:

```
public function modify_personal_information() {
        $this->data['userinfo'] = $this->personal_information_of_mine($userid);

        $this->load->view('layouts/header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('profile/personalinformation', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer', $this->data);
}
```

*method 2*:

```
public function check_url_if_exists() {
        $newportalurl = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $this->results = $this->profile_model->checknewportalurl($newportalurl);

        if ($this->results == 1) {
            $this->status['status'] = 1;
            $this->status['msg'] = 'This name is available. Thanks.';
        } else {
            $this->status['status'] = 0;
            $this->status['msg'] = 'This name is not available. See suggestions.';
        }
        $this->load->view('profile/layouts/availiability', $this->status);
        //or echo json_encode($this->status);
}
```

**profile/personalinformation.php (views)**

a form with `<div id="urlsuggestions"></div>`

**profile/layouts/availiability.php (views)**
where i am printing the message which i am getting from the `check_url()` function

**ajax.js (ajax)**

```
$('#newportalurl').blur(function() {
        var fval = $(this).val();
        var ifexists = fval.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');

        $.ajax(baseurl + "check/"+ifexists, function(data) {
            //i tried following things
            //alert(window.location);
            //$('#msgbox').html(data.msg).show().addClass('alert-success').delay(2000).fadeOut();
            //$('#urlsuggestions').load(window.location + 'modifypersonalinformation #urlsuggestions');
        });
    });
```

Now, I am trying to load the message to personalinformation view. What I am doing wrong or what will be the procedure to do it? I actually want to know the process how codeigniter handle them.

Comment: where you want to show the value returned from ajax??

Comment: I want to show value into `personalinformation` view

Comment: you have a separate div to display that??

Comment: separated means? I want to show at `<div id="urlsuggestions"></div>`

Comment: ok.. i will have a look at your code.

Comment: check the answer below, it is working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this, im not able to get response from your metod.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "<?= base_url("check/") ?>"+ifexists,
   success: function (data) {
       $("#urlsuggestions").html(data);// if you want to replace the data in div, use .html() 
                           or if you want to append the data user .append()
   }
});
```

Comment: BTW, thanks for your help. It has been worked after few modifications in controller and your's solution. :)